# Airflow - Send email with AWS SES

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, airflow, amazon-ses

Trying to send an email from apache airflow using AWS Simple Email Service (SES), and it's returning errors that are not helping me solve the problem. I believe it's a configuration issue within SES, but I'm not sure what to change.

General info:

- New SES instance, verified email.
- Airflow 1.10.10 running on Ubuntu 18.04 (local laptop).
- Same situation from EC2 instance on a separate AWS account.
- Running 1 DAG with a python operator that works fine.
- Sending email works with gmail smtp settings and an app password.

Abbreviated DAG code:

```
...
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
...
email_status = EmailOperator(
        task_id="sending_status_email",
        to="myverifiedemail@mydomain.com",
        subject="Test from SES",
        html_content="Trying to send an email from airflow through SES.",
        dag=dag
)
...
```

airflow.cfg SMTP Settings:

```
smtp_host = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = AWSUSERKEY
smtp_password = PASSWORDFROMAWSSMTP
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = myverifiedemail@mydomain.com
```

Errors Received while trying various changes to starttls, ssl, and port settings.

```
ERROR - (554, b'Transaction failed: Unsupported encoding us_ascii.')
ERROR - STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
ERROR - (SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER) wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure about the others but we just ran into this error today:

```
ERROR - (554, b'Transaction failed: Unsupported encoding us_ascii.')
```

This is the default value in the class's `__init__` method, which isn't valid:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/operators/email_operator.py#L63

You can fix it by passing in a valid value, like "utf-8":

```
email_status = EmailOperator(
        mime_charset='utf-8',
        task_id="sending_status_email",
        to="myverifiedemail@mydomain.com",
        subject="Test from SES",
        html_content="Trying to send an email from airflow through SES.",
        dag=dag
)
```